# Monitoring short-lived SCDF tasks

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have an issue where I try to monitor with Prometheus and SCDF some short-lived tasks. We are using micrometer and sending the metrics to rsocket proxy that is scraped by prometheus, as shown in the scdf documentation.

The metrics do show up in prometheus but due to the way prometheus works and the fact that rsocket proxy removes the metrics once they are scraped we can't really graph or use the metrics since this task runs at 12 or 24h intervals.

Does anyone have any experience with this and found a way to properly monitor these short-lived tasks that get triggered quite far apart without resorting to pushgateway?

Comment: Alexaned, not sure I completley understand your problem, but could it be that it is related to this micrometer issue? 
https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/prometheus-rsocket-proxy/issues/35

Comment: I don't think it's related, the metrics reach rsocket proxy just fine and prometheus can scrape them without issues. This is more of a if it's possible and how to do I sort of question. Since rsocket proxy removes the metrics once prometheus scrapes them is there any way to use them? The main problem being that for an entire day we would have only 2 data points inside prometheus at 12h intervals. For alerting I could use an abs function but I'm not sure how to handle Grafana since there are so few data points. Pushgateway would keep the data there but I'm not sure how rsocket would work.